# return statement in c ??? why this function always returning 20?

Tags: c, return, linear-search

```
int akki(int arr[],int m,int n){
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<m;i++){
      if(arr[i]==n)
           return i;

}
      return 20;
}
void main(){
int i,m,n,arr[10],a;
printf("Enter size of array:");
scanf("%d",&m);
printf("Enter %d elements of array:",m);
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
scanf("%d",arr[i]);
}
printf("Enter element to be searched:");
scanf("%d",&n);
a=akki(arr,m,n);
if(a!=20)
printf("Element found at %d position",a+1);
else
printf("Element not found");
```

}
IT is Returning 20 or some garbage value..even if condition matches... it is returning value of i.It is linear search function where m is size of array arr and n is element to be searched...
please explain in detail..i am new in c language

thankzzz in advance

Comment: Your function does `return 20;` , that will happen when it never found the element

Comment: Even if condition matches(arr[i]==n)..it is returning 20

Comment: @Akshay , No. It won't unless `i` is 20.

Comment: @Akshay the condition would have been true when *i was 20*

Comment: `akki` seems ok. The problem must be in the calling code. Show us a complete example, please.

Comment: Are you *sure* the condition will be true? Maybe the item you search for is at index 20? I suggest you change the returned value when no item is found to something that can't be a valid index, like `-1`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: take a look at complete code

Comment: When posting code, please use *copy-paste*, do not rewrite the code by hand as it might introduce errors not in the real code (or "fix" errors in the real code). For example, I doubt you have an expression such as `a!20` in your real code.

Comment: Also, please show your input, as well as expected *and* actual output.

Comment: you can take input 1 and 2... and if you search for 1.. it will give output..          element not found

Comment: Cool Guy's answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in your code. Change

```
scanf("%d",arr[i]);
```

To

```
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```

This is done because `scanf` expects an argument of type `int*` but you provide argument `arr[i]` which is of type `int`. Also add a check that ends the program if user inputs a number which is greater than 10 for the first `scanf`.

Comment: Thanku sooo much.. now my code is working correctly... but i have one doubt while taking string as input ..we do not use & in scanf...why????

Comment: If you provide an index for your `char[]` you would need an `&`. `char buffer[80];  scanf("%s", buffer);  /* is the same as  */ scanf("%s", &buffer[0]); `

Comment: @Akshay, Just keep in mind that the name of an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element. So,as KlasLindback has commented,`buffer` is equal to `&buffer[0]`

Comment: Got it sir.. thankzz fr your valuable answers..can you be in touch with me through facebook..please i need your help..i am having lots of problem in c and java.. my id is akshay.akky786@gmail.com .. please connect to me via facebook..thankzz again

Comment: @Akshay , Nah. I login on FB sometimes only. If you are facing problems just post it in StackOverflow. Be sure to post the exact code(and full code if it isn't too long) along with the problem and/or error messages. Be sure to post a question and the title should provide a hint to the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two reasons.

**Case 1** *[Much likely for _always_]*

Simple. Because your `if(arr[i]==n)` condition is not met, and `i<m` became false. It came out of `for()` loop and hence, `return 20`.

**case 2** *[Less likely for _always_]*

By chance, the value of `n` is present at the 21st location [index 20] in the input array.

Apart from the coding aspect, did you understand what's the logical purpose of this function? If not, begin with that. It searches for a specific value in an array of given length, and if no element of the array matches that value, it returns 20.

Now analyze your case, based on your input.

---

EDIT:

After seeing the complete code, as [Mr. CoolGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979994/2173917), use

```
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```

Just for more reference, you can look at Chapter 7.19.6.2, paragraph 12 , `%d` format specifier, which goes like

> ... The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.

In your code, `arr[i]` is of type `int`. What you need is a `int *`, i.e., `&arr[i]`.

Comment: Even if condition matches(arr[i]==n)..it is returning 20

Comment: @Akshay well, then `arr[i]` is equal to `n` for index `20`. That is another condition with which you could return `20`.

Comment: did you check the `n` is not `20`?

Comment: yes .. i have checked..i have taken only 2 elements in array..still it is returning 20 or some garbage

Comment: Ehm, you're missing a condition. You say it is because `if(arr[i]==n)` is never met, but it could be met.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did not understand you, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think you understood me now :-) Down-vote removed.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I realized my previous answer was _incomplete_. Thanks sir. :-)

Comment: Is question clear now..please help me if there any problem in calling function?